# Action button on 1 activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I'm using a navigation drawer for my application which includes fragments. I'm also using an action button. But when I use the drawer to change activities, the action button is on all the activities. I only want it on one of the fragments. This is my code

```
package com.colourity.snatsh;

import com.colourity.snatsh.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.colourity.snatsh.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import com.colourity.snatsh.model.NavDrawerItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    public HomeFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

And these are the errors.

`The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type HomeFragment must override or implement a supertype method   HomeFragment.java

The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type HomeFragment HomeFragment.java   /Snatsh/src/com/colourity/snatsh

The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, MenuInflater) in the type Fragment is not applicable for the arguments (Menu)`

When I do this in my `MainActivity` it works fine, but when I move it over to my `HomeFragment` the errors show.

Comment: Is `The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu, MenuInflater) in the type Fragment is not applicable for the arguments (Menu)` not clear enough? Here's a hint: you need to change the method signature like the error says.

Comment: Then I would start by reading some Java books before diving into Android development. Basically, `Fragment` and `Activity` have an `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, but they have different signatures; one takes a `ManuInflater` the other only takes a `Menu`

Answer (score 1):

> but when I move it over to my HomeFragment the errors show.

You need to make sure that you are using the `onCreateoptionsMenu()` signature that corresponds to the `Fragment` class. You can delete this method in the `Fragment`, then start typing its name and then use your IDEs autocomplete functionality to use the correct method signature.

Comment: I'm new to this, so any help would be great. So i'd add this to my `HomeFragment`?
`@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: No. You cannot inflate a layout in the `Fragment`'s `onCreate()`; you use `onCreateView()` for that. The method you posted is `Activity`'s `onCreate()`. `Fragment` `onCreate()`'s signature is `public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)`; it is `public`

Comment: So how would I start?

Comment: Same issue. More detail and maybe an example would be nice. @Emmanuel

Comment: As I said, I'm new and I figured out the best way for me to learn is to have the solution, since this is the only piece of fragment I have, and I'm working on a deadline. @Emmanuel

Comment: I'm just asking for a solution

Comment: I disagree with you when you say the best way to learn is to be granted the solution. If you want to see how `Fragment`'s work, create a new blank project and see how it is implemented.

Comment: Why would you downvote my answer? it is a valid explanation for your problem. Is it because I am not giving you code?

Comment: I didn't down vote anything? You said I should read the fragments guide. Maybe a link would be helpful. And everyone has a different way of learning, please keep that in mind